# Error converting a string in to datetime object

Tags: python-3.6

I am reading a line from a text file. It contains the date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I am trying to convert it to datetime object so as to find the difference between two dates.

```
l = datetime.strptime(last_execution_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Its throwing an error:ValueError: unconverted data remains:

But when I am using below its working perfectly fine

```
l = datetime.strptime('2019-01-25',"%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

My complete code looks something like this:

```
def incoming_mails_duration():
   f = open('last_script_execution_time.txt', 'r')
   last_execution_date = f.readline()
   print(last_execution_date)
   print(type(last_execution_date))
   l = datetime.strptime(last_execution_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
   print(l)
   print(type(l))
   present_date = date.today()
   delta_days = abs((present_date - l).days)
   f.close()
```

Why I am getting the above error when I am passing the string as variable read from a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `f.readline()` returns string with `\n` in the end. You either have to strip the newline character or include it inside `strptime` format argument.

#### Solution 1:

```py
last_execution_date = f.readline().strip()
```

#### Solution 2:

```py
l = datetime.strptime(last_execution_date,"%Y-%m-%d\n").date() # Note \n
```

#### Note

Also it is good practice to open files with `with` statement. This is a safe way to handle files. File will be safely closed even if exception occurred inside `with` block.

```py
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        # Work with line here
        pass
```